# Java - Instantiate Runnable Inside Loop

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, runnable

I want to create multiple `Runnable` object for alarm application which will execute tasks in the time specified by user.

I try to do it inside loop like the following:

```
ScheduledExecutorService wait;
List<Runnable> listens = new ArrayList<>();
int i;
private void playAlarmOnInit(){
wait = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
    // loop through the tasks to get times            
    int counts = getDays().size();        
    for(i = 0; i < counts; i++){
        if(!getDays().get(i).isEmpty()) {
        Runnable listen = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(!getDays().get(i).equals("Everyday")) {
                    System.out.println(getDays().get(i) + " " + getTimes().get(i));                                        
                } else {
                    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy");
                    Date date = new Date();
                    String time = format.format(date);
                    System.out.println(time + " " + getTimes().get(i)); 
                }
//                System.out.println(" " + getTimes().get(i)); 
                    }
            };
            wait.scheduleAtFixedRate(listen, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

And it does nothing.
Why the code above does not work?

Comment: what do you mean by `it does nothing`? Exception? not a single `Runnable` is being executed?

Comment: nothing. not even an exeception nor Runnable is being executed.

Comment: are you sure `getDays()` is actually returning something, like @John Tribe mentioned in his answer?

Comment: Yes, I tested it. It is a List.

Comment: @JohnnyAW Either way, `i` is pretty much guaranteed to be equal to `getDays().size()` when any of the tasks are executed. So your answer is essentially correct. There may be other issues too, but users who won't post MCVEs can't really expect others to be able to identify all possible problems: no-one here is clairvoyant.

Comment: @KeepMove The question wasn't about whether or not it was a list. The question was whether or not it had anything in it.

Comment: I knew, I just want to confirm that everything is OK but that `Runnable` inside loop.

Comment: The first place you are going wrong here is declaring `i` as an instance variable. It should be local to the loop (i.e. `for (int i = 0 ; ...)`). Start from there, and when there are compile errors, those compile errors are telling you that you are trying to do something that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I didn't have any choice other than put it in class level, because it will be denied if declare it as local variable.

Comment: @KeepMove it will be denied, because the variable is not final, and the value will be changed at the time your `Runnable` will be executed. To fix that create a new final variable, that you can use in the `Runnable`, but keep `i` in the loop

Comment: @KeepMove That was exactly my point: "If there are compile errors, those errors are telling you that you are trying to do something that does not make sense". You're not supposed to refer to the same variable there. That is exactly what JohnnyAW is showing you how to avoid in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is probably that you use `i` in your `Runnable`. At the time your `Runnable` is being executed, the value of `i` should be equal `counts`, so `getDays().get(i)` in the `Runnuble` should actually throw a `IndexOutOfBoundException`. Try to use `try-catch` and check, if there is an exception. To fix that you should create a new final variable and use it in the `Runnable`:

```
if(!getDays().get(i).isEmpty()) {
    final int runnableI = i;
    Runnable listen = new Runnable() {
         @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!getDays().get(runnableI).equals("Everyday")) {
            ....
```

Or you could even store the day as the final variable:

```
final String day = getDays().get(i);
```

and use it in the `Runnable`

Comment: No, that's not the problem. If I put the `for loop` inside `Runnable` then it executes normally.

Comment: @KeepMove Well, it would. I don't think you understand this answer. If the for loop surrounds the creation of the runnable, and references the loop variable, then by the time the runnables are executed, `i` will be equal to `getDays().size()` and you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (which you won't see, because it's being swallowed by the executor).

Comment: @James_D exactly

Comment: @KeepMove please try the workaround I suggested and see if it will help or not

Comment: And if you put the loop *inside* the runnable, then when you execute the runnable the loop initialization sets `i` back to zero.

Comment: @JohnnyAW I did, and the result is just the same. That's why I said that's not the problem.

Comment: @KeepMove can you post the code after you applied my workaround?

Comment: @KeepMove don't forget, that you use `i` to get time without checking the size of `getTime()`: `getTimes().get(i)`. You should wrap your code in `Runnable` with `try-catch` to see if there is an `Exception` being swallowed...

Answer (score -1):

maybe the main program closing before threads are started. Add Thread.sleep(5000), after:

```
wait.scheduleAtFixedRate(listen, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Thread.spleep(5000)
```

or maybe your list (getDays) is empty.